# Problem defining same column twice using @Column in Spring Boots

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am facing a problem when I define the same column, second time.

In the Document.class that column have defined already and as soon as I define @Column(name = "docid") again into  Test.class, it failed.

Document.class

```
@Column(name = "docid")
  protected String docId;
```

Test.class

```
 @Column(name = "docid")
  protected String docIds;
```

Build failing with error

```
contextLoads FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException
                Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException
```

Comment: Do both these classes have a mapping each other? and update the question with how you call the column.

Comment: Update the quiz with both Document and Test classes with table definitions and other columns.  Have you tried with different column name and was it succeed?

Comment: @DevThiman yes it works fine with different column name

Comment: can you provide the full stack trace of the given error.

Comment: @DevThiman I have found the alternative solution to resolve my issue. I would rather calling database column in the script than by object and it works perfectly fine.